# Yii Password Encryption

Tags: php, yii

I can't understnad why this is not working. This code snippt is in my `userscontroller.php` Does it need to be elsewhere?

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Users;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Users']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
        $model->password = crypt_SHA_512($model->password,'salt');
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->users_id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Comment: Everything looks fine. What is not working ? The encryption ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. the passwords are not being encrypted no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making one mistake of not handling errors, and this is why you cannot understand why this is not working.

Use this snippet to understand why.

```
 if($model->save())
     $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->users_id));
 else
     print_r($model->getErrors());
```

The correct way would be to call the model validate() function before saving, and display the error in your view.

```
 if ($model->validate()) {
    if ($model->save()) {
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->users_id));
    }
 }

 $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model
 ));
```

and in your view :

```
<?php 
    $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm' ...);
 ?>

  <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

  <div class="row">
      <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
      <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a salt and encode password by:

```
$salt = substr(str_shuffle("./ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345‌​6789"), 0, 8);
$model->password = crypt($passwordInput, '$6$'.$salt);// '$6$' for SHA_512
```

And for confirmation:

```
if (crypt($passwordInput, $hashed) == $hashed) { 
  // Valid action
} else { 
  // Invalid action
}
```

**Alternatively:**

> You can use [Yii password helper.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPasswordHelper)

Hash your password by:

```
$model->password = CPasswordHelper::hashPassword($password);
```

And for confirmation:

```
if (CPasswordHelper::verifyPassword($password, $hash))
    // password is good
else
    // password is bad
```

Comment: Hi there, I've actually just got it encrypted by removing the spaces around the = sign however i cannot get it to sha512 could i put this `$model->PassWord=crypt($model->PassWord, '$6$', 'salt');`

Comment: And i have just attempted your method and got Undefined variable: PassWordInput  (the P and W are ment to be capitalized)